# Can US & Europe stop all chips supply to Russia & China?

Tags: china, russia

Modern economy is built on semiconductor

West holds all the key component of this sector, so instead of fighting a war with china & russia, can they just cut the whole supply of chips and other modern technology & equipment to both countries and send them back into stone ages

As in case of Huawei we have already seen trump ban caused it to shut down its mobile business operation and even after so much R&D they cant produce high end chip by themselves

So i want to understand what is stopping USA from stopping all chips supply to Russia & China ?

Comment: Hi! You posted this as a question, but it seems to be a monologue?

Comment: Had it benefited the bloodthirsty, warmonger US beyond just public validation, it would have continued the chip war in a less nonchalant manner. Here's a related discussion that might be of interest: [What would happen if China were to suddenly stop all trade with the US?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/52623/42394)

Comment: @Citrus please explain how USA is a bloodthirsty warmonger in Ukraine? that is simply false

Comment: Regarding the question: the chips are created in China. So wouldn't it be China blocking chips supply to USA?

Comment: @user253751 I didn't mention the Russia-Ukraine war. If we still look at this situation, the US meddled in the unseating of the previously elected Ukrainian Prez. which led to the annexation of Crimea. [Here](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-26079957)'s the infamous Nuland-Pyatt telephone conversation. In the recent times, Moscow's security guarantees from NATO were never replied. This is in some sense similar to the hostility the US faced from Cuba which led to a failed invasion.

Comment: @user253751 I am not condoning Russia's actions. That being said, Russia's war crimes seem to be a drop in the ocean compared to USA's.